# Change local branch to a different one

Tags: git

I was working on a `release/1.0` branch and I started working on some changes. Unadvertedly I commited these changes to the same branch I was in, that is `release/1.0`

Now this branch has locally a few changes that are not on the remote `release/1.0` branch.

Turns out our repo system does not allow for pushing changes directly to release branches, but we should create pull requests instead.

So now I have my `bugfix/my-branch` (branching remote `release/1.0`) where I would like the changes that are locally on release/1.0 to be.

How can I "move" those changes to this new branch and discard them locally for `release/1.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try a [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

---

Optional Pre-Step:
If you are not sure (or don't know) which branch your bugfix should be based on do the following (because you mentioned that you already have a `bugfix/my-branch` branch.

```
$ git branch -m bugfix/my-branch starting-point
```

---

First name your branch as what it really is:

```
$ git branch -m bugfix/my-branch
```

Then rebase it into the correct position (assuming `starting-point`)

```
$ git rebase --onto starting-point release/1.0 bugfix/my-branch
```

This will move everything between `release/1.0` and `bugfix/my-branch` (all the commits you did) onto the brach were you should have branched off.

---

And after everything went well you can safely delete the `starting-point` branch.

```
$ git branch -d starting-point
```

Comment: then what is develop?

Comment: The branch that your `bugfix/my-branch` is branched from. I added steps to simply use the already existing `bugfix/my-branch` branch. I hope that it is not too confusing this way.

Answer (score 1):

One option here would be to `git cherry-pick` the commits you made on `release/1.0` to the `bugfix/my-branch` branch, and then delete the commits on the former release branch:

```
git checkout bugfix/my-branch
git cherry-pick A^..B          # replace 'A' with earliest commit, 'B' with latest commit
...
git checkout release/1.0
git reset --hard HEAD~N        # replace N with the number of commits you made on release
```

The solution assumes that you have *not* pushed the `release/1.0` branch containing your recent commits to the public remote yet, so no one else has seen them.  In this case, it is safe to remove these commits by resetting to before you made them.

Note on syntax of cherry-pick range syntax:

The command `git cherry-pick A..B` will only work if commit `A` is *older* than commit `B`.  In addition, commit `A` itself will be *excluded* from the range, while `B` will be included.  So, to get the range of commits from `A` to `B`, with both ends being included, use `git cherry-pick A^..B`.

Comment: Did you mean `A~..B`?  I'd also replace `HEAD~N` with `A~`, and for my own use I'd just replace the last two commands with `git checkout -B release/1.0 A~` or more likely just `git branch -f release/1.0 A~`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
git checkout bugfix/my-branch
git cherry-pick release/1.0
git checkout release/1.0
git reset --hard origin/release/1.0
```

(providing your remote is named `origin`)